# Why we do not use fetch type in Hibernate hbm file?

Tags: java, hibernate

Why we do not use fetch type in Hibernate `HBM` file?

Why only annotated class will include fetch type when we write code for relationships?

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=Cast.class)

@JoinColumn(name="id2", referencedColumnName="id")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a little bit more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in XML file too. Annotations are more readable and easier to process than xml file. Look:

```
<many-to-one name="employee" 
    class="com.myapp.Employee"
    cascade="merge"
    lazy="false"
    fetch="select">
```